# Yeoman 'grunt test' fails on clean project with 'port already in use'

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

With:

- Mac OS 10.8.4
- Node 0.10.12
- npm 1.3.1
- grunt-cli 0.1.9
- yo 1.0.0-rc.1
- bower 0.9.2
- generator-angular@0.3.0

I encounter the following error with a clean `yo angular` project, followed by `grunt server` then `grunt test`:

```
Running "connect:test" (connect) task  
Fatal error: Port 9000 is already in use by another process.
```

I'm new to Yeoman and am stumped. I've deleted my original project and created a new one in a fresh folder just to make sure I wasn't overlooking any invisible configs. I restarted the machine to make sure I wasn't running any temporary server processes I had forgotten about. After all attempts, the basic server starts fine, attaches to Chrome, and the watcher updates the browser on any changes. (Notably, the server is running on 9000, which seems odd for the test-runner to also be trying to use 9000.) But I get that same error on attempting to start the test runner.

Is this something I can fix, or an issue I should report to the Yeoman team? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the port for the test task in Gruntfile.js? As you mentionend, livereload and test use the same port by default, so that might be the problem.

Comment: That's the weird thing: they both appear to be using the same data. If I change connect.options.port to 9001, then both livereload and test try to use 9001, and all I get is a different port number in the error. I'm baffled as to why it would be written that way, and why there wouldn't be two separate configs with separate port numbers.

Comment: I guess the default config does not assume that you run the server and test at the same time. Maybe it's expected to run the tests automatically when files are changed, or run them before the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new config property: `connect.test.options.port`, and set that to 9001. Now they appear to be running properly on separate ports.

Note also that the `Gruntfile.js` is overriding the `singleRun` property in `karma.conf.js`. Comment/cut that out if you want the config in `karma.conf.js` to work properly.

EDIT 11/4/13: 
[The issue](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/375) was reported by others as well and seems to have been addressed with changes to generator-angular.

Answer (score 5):

Add `port: 9001` to test, like this:

```
test: {
  options: {
    port: 9001,
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, see my answer above, where I mention setting `connect.test.options.port` to 9001.

Comment: I tried this but no luck either, using the polymer-generator

Answer (score 1):

After I change the port, there is a XHR error, 
`The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:9000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:9090' is therefore not allowed access.`
It was 9000 initially and then I change the grunt

```
connect: {
  main: {
    options: {
      port: 9090
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it this is cos of server issue, not a client.