# Grunt : JASMINE is not supported anymore

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, karma-runner

i created an angular application with yeoman, when i executed grunt command i got the following error

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
WARN [config]: JASMINE is not supported anymore.
        Please use `frameworks = ["jasmine"];` instead.
WARN [config]: JASMINE_ADAPTER is not supported anymore.
        Please use `frameworks = ["jasmine"];` instead.
WARN [config]: LOG_INFO is not supported anymore.
  Please use `karma.LOG_INFO` instead.
ERROR [config]: Config file must export a function!
  module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
      // your config
    });
  };
```

how do i solve this error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It's just those two predefined terms (JASMINE and JASMINE_ADAPTER)
>   that should not be used any more. All you have to do is open the
>   config file ./config/karma.conf.js and comment out those terms and add
>   frameworks = ["jasmine"];.

Via [Yasuhiro Yoshida](http://yasuhiroyoshida.github.io/2013/05/20/jasmine-is-not-supported,-angular_scenario-is-not-supported,-and-econnrefused/)

Comment: can u please share the link ?

Comment: you could have copy and past the line in google too
http://yasuhiroyoshida.github.io/2013/05/20/jasmine-is-not-supported,-angular_scenario-is-not-supported,-and-econnrefused/

Comment: `Fatal error: Port 9000 is already in use by another process.`
but this port is the grunt server !

Comment: i tried . [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396727/yeoman-grunt-test-fails-on-clean-project-with-port-already-in-use/18295872#18295872)

Comment: am getting `ERROR [config]: Config file must export a function!
  module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
      // your config
    });
  };
`
any idea how to solve ?

Answer (score 2):

apart from @sheplu's answer, there are additional changes that need to be done in karma.conf.js, you can see it in https://gist.github.com/sivakumar-kailasam/6421378

this gist solves your problem of **'Config file must be a export a function!'**

The official docs has these changes as well http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html